# Chinese Characters in Stata

Tags: windows-7, stata

I am working on a data set that contains Chinese characters. Stata displays these as gibberish and I need to be able to read these. I could not find a Chinese language pack for Stata. Does something like this exist?

I am using Windows 7 Professional and StataSE 13 (64 bit).

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to `Control Panel->Language->Advanced Settings`.
2. Click into `Apply language settings to the welcome screen, system accounts, and new user accounts`.
3. In `Administrative` tab, under `language for non-Unicode programs`, change it to Chinese (Simplified). You might need to change system locale if your computer wasn’t initially set to be `located in China`.

Answer (score 0):

For those who arrive here via Google. There have been substantial improvements since this question was answered:

[See here for more information on setting locale in Stata 15 and later.](https://www.stata.com/stata15/chinese-interface/)

> "If your computer language is set to Chinese (zh_CN) and its region is set to China, Stata will automatically default to its Simplified Chinese setting. To change languages manually using Windows or Unix, select Edit > Preferences > User-interface language... using Mac, select Stata 16 > Preferences > User-interface language... You can also change the language using the set locale_ui command."